# Regular expression for single pairs of (nested) brackets, BUT excluding inter-leaved ones?

Tags: regex, parsing, state-machine, regular-language

There are plenty of solutions on SO and elsewhere for matching pairs of parentheses or brackets, but none that I can find or come up with to exclude inter-leaved items. What is the solution to this challenge:

```
Write a regular expression for a string containing any number of X 
and single pairs of < > and { } which may be nested but not 
inter-leaved. For example these strings are allowed:

XXX<XX{X}XXX>X
X{X}X<X>X{X}X<X>X

But these are not allowed:

XXX<X<XX>>XX
XX<XX{XX>XX}XX
```

Can this be done with a regular expression (finite automaton) at all? Doesn't it require a pushdown automaton?

Apart from not interleaving, note the requirement for single pairs, meaning that nesting may be only one level deep, of different bracket types, as shown.

There is no preference for which regex engine/language is used.

Comment: @AKSingh OP is supposed to write a regular expression. Using stack is not a regular expression.

Comment: I'd think of something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/wu39fy/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `X` be shorthand for `[^<>{}]`. Then the regular expression required is:

```
(X|<(X|{X*})*>|{(X|<X*>)*})*
```

Or, written out in full,

```
([^<>{}]|<([^<>{}]|{[^<>{}]*})*>|{([^<>{}]|<[^<>{}]*>)*})*
```

See https://regex101.com/r/f93EOs/1

Comment: Simple and rigorous! I'm enjoying the "Let X be..." way of thinking about it, as it simplifies the task and leads you to the correct solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```php
^[^<>{}]*(?:(?:<[^<>]*>|{[^{}]*})+[^<>{}]*)*$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/I9scts/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^<>{}]*                 any character except: '<', '>', '{', '}'
                           (0 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^<>]*                   any character except: '<', '>' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      {                        '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^{}]*                   any character except: '{', '}' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      }                        '}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^<>{}]*                 any character except: '<', '>', '{', '}'
                             (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: I didn't expect the solution would be this simple and elegant. I was too focused on trying to exclude the interleaved opening bracket, while the solution is to exclude the closing one. Very neat, thank you!

Comment: `<[^<>]*>` certainly rejects nested angle brackets. But it allows unmatched (or excessively nested) braces. Or am I missing something?

Comment: rici is right, as his proof shows. I was happy to overlook the unmatched braces being allowed as the challenge didn't address the issue, but I missed that the regex would allow excessive nesting. I've now accepted rici's answer. This answer will be useful in other use cases though, I still like it!